# How do i remove the jailbreak on my stolen iPhone 5c?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone

I had my iPhone stolen earlier today. I went through the steps of trying to find it using Find My Phone, etc.

I ended up getting my phone back miraculously through a system of Find My Phone and just my own personal investigation, but when I got it back it seems to be different. All my apps are gone, and I'm not sure if this was part of the Wipe My Phone I did but there is also Cydia and Pingu installed on my iPhone. I'm pretty sure those involve jailbroken iPhones.

My question: is my iPhone jailbroken, and what steps do I go through to reverse that? I don't want a jailbroken iPhone.

Comment: Considering that Cydia is on your iPhone, yes I'm sure it was jail broken. And yes, remotely wiping your phone would remove your apps. However I'm a little surprised that they were able to move past the activation lock.

Comment: Someone stole your iPhone and jailbroke it -- but that didn't wipe out your existing settings, so Find My iPhone still worked. Oh, and the thief who smart enough to do that (and pull the SIM) didn't disable Find My iPhone? Pull the other one.

Answer (score 10):

Cydia is installed when the iPhone is jailbroken. iOS 8 Pangu Jailbreak installs the Pangu app during the jailbreak process. So the answer to your question is Yes, the iPhone is jailbroken.

### How to remove the jailbreak from your iPhone

- Connect your phone to iTunes
- Do a factory reset
- Restore back to the most recent iPhone backup

Following the above steps can restore the iPhone to factory condition and restore back to the recent backup through iTunes.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I still wanted to says it.

I think he gave you a different phone. If the phone was already jailbroken and the sim was taken out, I think it won't show up in Find My Phone (unless the guy goofed up did some silly things).

I think he gave you someone else's (already hacked) phone and kept yours so he finish hacking it.

If you know your phone has any unique features, like a scratch or something, be sure to check that the phone he gave you also has it. If not, it's probably not your phone.

**Why would he hack your phone you ask? Because it makes it very easy to do identity theft on you.**

What you should do now:

1. Change the passwords to ***everything in your life*** (no joke).
2. If you have email setup on your phone, change its password and
   read your Sent mail from the day you lost your phone to the day
   you changed your password.
3. If you ever used a credit card to buy things with your phone,
   contact your bank, tell them the card may be compromised
   and ask for a new card.
4. If you had any classified/confidential data on your phone, do
   whatever you must do to mitigate the consequences of that
   information going public.

Now, all that being said, he is probably not a professional since he let you track him down to his house, so the steps I mentioned above might not be necessary. Also, if your phone is password protected and you did the Wipe My Phone before he hacked it, your data and passwords are probably safe.

But regardless, you should still exercise caution and watch your finances/identity very closely for at least a couple months just in case.

Good luck!